# Multiple Windows at QtCreator startup

Tags: 13.04, qt-creator

I'm using QtCreator for a while. No problems everything worked fine. But, when I started some hours before it opens with multiple windows named QtCreator along with one main QtCreator window. Others were just frames of the desktop as shown in the image link below. What may be the problem?

[image]

Comment: Same problem here with xUbuntu 13.04 (updated from 12.10) and reinstalling (with removing of configuration files) does not fix the problem

Comment: @niccomatik We can work normally by just opening QtCreator and instead of opening recent project from the main interface just go through File->Open Recent Project and then select your project. That will work as normal...

Comment: This appears to be a deeper library issue and likely not limited to just QtCreator. Applications I've written using Qt exhibit the same blank window behavior when file select dialogs are shown. This is annoying for users and devs.

Comment: This sounds like a bug, and you should file a bug report on this.  See [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) for details on how to go about filing a bug report.

Comment: I have the same issue with Ubuntu 13.04 and QtCreator 2.8.1, the latest version from the software centre. Now I reported the bug at [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtcreator/+bug/1231515)