# “Qml2Puppet” windows appearing in Qt Creator

Tags: qt-creator

Using Qt Creator 2.7.0, when I switch to design view of a qml file, I'm now getting 3 additional, unresponsive windows opening up, all with the title “Qml2Puppet”. This didn't used to happen.

I've  un-installed and re-installed Qt Creator (using sudo apt-get purge qtcreator
and sudo apt-get install qtcreator), but this hasn't solved it.  I've also deleted the QtProject.conf, Trolltech.conf and QtProject items in ~/.config.

Any ideas for what else to try? I'm using Kubuntu 13.04, 64 bit.

Note: this is a different issue to [Multiple Windows at QtCreator startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297104/multiple-windows-at-qtcreator-startup) (where the windows are untitled and appear at startup).

Comment: +1, got the same problem. It's extremely annoying

Answer (score 0):

Yes, annoying. I hope, soon, it is fixed. Waiting is annoying also?

Well, actually, I have a workaround on this. Fortunately, clicking on "design" tab launching `qml2puppet` executable located on /usr/bin.

By this mechanism, we can substitute the `qml2puppet` executable with our own script. The script will execute the real qml2puppet and beside, suppressing the "ilegal" windows.

## Steps :

1. Rename `qml2puppet` into `qml2puppet.bak`

   > sudo mv /usr/bin/qml2puppet /usr/bin/qml2puppet.bak
2. Make our executable script

   - Create file

     > gksudo gedit /usr/bin/qml2puppet
   - Copy the full-script [here](https://gist.github.com/Abdillah/8206655) into the script
   - Make it executable

     > sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/qml2puppet
3. Download script component for controlling windows : `wmctrl`

   > sudo apt-get install wmctrl
4. Well done. Try it! When you face other problem following those step, you can comment below.

Comment: @reader : any of you feel inconvenient with the method used to post the script (GitHub Gist) can help me move and format the script here.